# Flashing LED's and use of switch

Tags: led, switches

Is it possible to wire the LED's in the following way??(shown in the rough diagram of my circuit)

I want the LED's flashing alternatively, ie - D1, D3, D5, D7 (A LED's) are powered by just the transistor and the rest (B LED's) are by the op-amp and transistor (op-amp inverts the signal making it flash alternatively)

The switches are to control the "shutting" of a row and column in order to have just one LED blinking. That is if only LED D3 should be blinking Switch 1 and Switch 2 should be closed, with the rest of the switches open.

my question is: Is it possible to connect the LED's as shown in the figure??

and in order to switch just LED D3 ON, SW1 and SW2 are used, use of SW1 would also switch LED D1 ON, how do i avoid that??

Thanks!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1bgxO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you consider starting again with a small microcontroller.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2farlDI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve apart from flashing LEDs in multiple combinations where the specific combinations are one of a set controlled by a smaller number of switches. It doesn't matter, the above circuit will work, it's then just a matter of software.